# What is the difference between ManagementObject and ManagementBaseObject

Tags: .net, wmi, wql

When i Compiled the following both codes it gives same result (I think so).

```
//ManagementObject :
SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("Win32_Environment");
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
foreach (ManagementObject envVar in searcher.Get())
  Console.WriteLine("Variable : {0}, Value = {1}",envVar["Name"], envVar["VariableValue"]);

//ManagementBaseObject :
SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("Win32_Environment");
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
foreach (ManagementBaseObject envVar in searcher.Get())
  Console.WriteLine("Variable : {0}, Value = {1}",envVar["Name"], envVar["VariableValue"]);
```

what is the difference between both code execution...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this particular case, there is no difference.

The `ManagementObjectSearcher.Get()` method returns a [`ManagementObjectCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementobjectcollection.aspx) which is a collection of  [`ManagementBaseObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementbaseobject.aspx). This means that the collection can contain instances of type `ManagementBaseObject` or of any type that is descended from `ManagementBaseObject`.

However, the `ManagementBaseObject` is designed as a base class, which means that in reality, it won't be instantiated, but instead, it's descended classes will be instantiated. Note that this is a just a convention, and it is not enforced by the language or framework.

Additionally, since the only class in the framework that (directly) inherits the `ManagementBaseObject` is [`ManagementObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementobject.aspx), the `Get()` effectively returns a collection of `ManagementObject` instances. Note that this is just the current situation, and nothing prevents the creation of additional `ManagementBaseObject` inheritors.

So, with all mentioned caveats, that means, that if you use only properties defined in the base class (and not overriden) you could iterate either way, and the code will behave exactly the same. In your code you use only the [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementbaseobject.item.aspx), which is indeed defined, and not overriden, in the `ManagementBaseObject` class.

If you want an example of code that will fail for one loop, and work in the other, you could try any of the properties defined on `ManagementObject`, like, for example, [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementobject.path.aspx):

```
foreach (ManagementObject envVar in searcher.Get())
  Console.WriteLine("Path : {0}, Value = {1}",envVar.Path.Path); //works

foreach (ManagementBaseObject envVar in searcher.Get())
  Console.WriteLine("Path : {0}, Value = {1}",envVar.Path.Path); //compile error
```

Comment: Note however, that the fact that the first version using `ManagementObject` works is only due to the fact that there are currently no other types deriving from `ManagementBaseObject`. It is nothing that is guaranteed by the contract of the `Get()` method.

Comment: Added a bit stronger wording to emphasize that fact. While I doubt that the design of these classes will ever change (and they have been around [for a long time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementobjectcollection%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)), using this code means relying on an unproven and unsupported assumption.

Answer (score 2):

You should preferably use `ManagementBaseObject` here. The `Get()` method returns a (non-generic) [`ManagementObjectCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementobjectcollection.aspx) which contains `ManagementBaseObject`-derived types, including `ManagementObject` and `ManagementClass`.

The first version may work for your particular query, but in general you might get an invalid cast exception.

If you only need to consider objects of type `ManagementObject` you might consider the following version:

```
var query = new SelectQuery("Win32_Environment");
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
foreach (var envVar in searcher.Get().OfType<ManagementObject>())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Variable: {0}, Value = {1}", 
        envVar["Name"], envVar["VariableValue"]);
}
```

Comment: While it is true that he should stick to `ManagementBaseObject` because things can change in the future and we all know how the story goes regarding assumptions... `ManagementClass` derives from `ManagementObject` so your `searcher.Get().OfType<ManagementObject>()` would return both `ManagementObject` and `ManagementClass` objects.